# Dojo toggler not working with display: none

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, display

This is a sample of what works:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/dom","dojo/fx/Toggler","dojo/topic","dojo/domReady!"],

    function(dom,Toggler,topic){
var toggler = new Toggler ({
    node: "test"
});
alert("something");     
toggler.hide();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">This is just a test.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I add `display: none` to my div (and using `toggler.show()`), it stops working. This is a sample of what does not work:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/dom","dojo/fx/Toggler","dojo/topic","dojo/domReady!"],

    function(dom,Toggler,topic){
var toggler = new Toggler ({
    node: "test"
});
alert("something");     
toggler.show();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" style="display:none">This is just a test.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Question:**

- Why is this happening?
- Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I am using dojo or its toggler module?
- What is the alternative to toggler (if any), which I can use with `display: none`?

---

**Note:**

I have checked various possibly duplicate links but they all provide workarounds as mentioned below:-

- Using `dojo.style("test","display","")` works, but in complex projects it messes with the alignment etc.
- Removing `display:none` or replacing it with `visibility: hidden` is not an option for me. It works, but I would like to avoid workarounds if an actual solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

The Toggler Animation uses the fadeIn and fadeOut functions to change the visibility of the Node. which in-turn updates the opacity of the node. which means, node is still there, its just not visible.

You setting the display to none does not update when you use the Toggler to show. Also, setting the display property allows other node to occupy the place held by current node.

So, you need to decide what is that you want. whether you want to use Toggler or use dojo.style. You you wish to continue with Toggler, then instead of display you need to set the opacity to 0.

Comment: Oh! But earlier I was using a previous version of dojo, which instead of toggler.show had dojo.widget.byId(...).show which worked perfectly fine with display none.

Comment: Which version of dojo and what type of widget are you talking about? If I consider 1.6, Then only widget of Dialog type would have supported that. Again, you could do the same in the latest verion if the dijit/widget supports show and hide methods.

Comment: The previous version I was using was 0.4.4 and the version I am now using is 1.10